What is the reference for the dua "Allahumma a'izzal-Islama wal-Muslimeen..."
I was looking for the reference for the following dua:

اللهُمَّ أَعِزَّ الإِسْلامَ وَالمُسْلِمِينَ، اللهُمَّ أَعِزَّ
الإِسْلامَ وَالمُسْلِمِينَ، وَأَذِلَّ الشِّرْكَ وَالمُشْرِكِينَ
وَدَمِّرْ أَعْدآءَ الدِّينِ وَاحْمِ حَوْزَةَ الإسْلامِ يَا رَبَّ
العَالَمِينَ
Allahumma a'izzal-Islama wal-Muslimeen, Allahumma a'izzal-Islama
wal-Muslimeen, wa adhillash-shirka wal-Mushrikeen, wa dammir
a'daa’ad-deen, wahmi hawzatal-Islami ya rabbal-3alameen
O Allah! Raise the standing of Islam and the Muslims, O Allah raise
the standing and the Muslims, and degrade the standing of Kufr and the
Kaafireen, and Shirk and the Mushrikeen. Destroy the enemies of the
Deen, and protect the lands of Islam, O Lord of the Worlds.

What is the source of this dua?
